# Meaning of // operator in perl

Tags: perl, operators

I am new to perl. Can anyone please explain the meaning of `//` operator in perl.

Comment: There is a `man perlop` for such questions

Comment: Actually `//` is new to Perl as well. Perl 5.10.0 (2007)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's the definedness operator. The expression:

```
A // B
```

will return `A` if it's defined, otherwise `B`.

It's very useful for getting default values if the source of the information is not defined, with things like:

```
$actualBalance = $balanceFromBank // 0;
```

or:

```
$confirmation = $userInput // "N";
```

See [the relevant part of the perlop page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) for more detail and make a link of [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html) for future reference, since Google searches and the punctuational Perl code don't mix that well :-)

Answer (score 9):

The `//` operator is a *logical defined-or*. [Perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Logical-Defined-Or) says:

> Although it has no direct equivalent in C, Perl's // operator is
>   related to its C-style or. In fact, it's exactly the same as ||,
>   except that it tests the left hand side's definedness instead of its
>   truth. Thus, EXPR1 // EXPR2 returns the value of EXPR1 if it's
>   defined, otherwise, the value of EXPR2 is returned. (EXPR1 is
>   evaluated in scalar context, EXPR2 in the context of // itself).
>   Usually, this is the same result as defined(EXPR1) ? EXPR1 : EXPR2
>   (except that the ternary-operator form can be used as a lvalue, while
>   EXPR1 // EXPR2 cannot). This is very useful for providing default
>   values for variables. If you actually want to test if at least one of
>   $a and $b is defined, use defined($a // $b) .

In short: It returns the left side if that expression is defined (as in not `undef`), or the right side.

```
my $foo = undef;
say $foo // 42;
# 42

my $bar = 'bar';
say $bar // 42;
# bar
```

Comment: Have to add that `//` is quite a unique operator. And it's quite useful, too: often it's just not enough to test for 'falsiness' only (with PHP's `?:` and Perl/JavaScript `||`). Sadly, it became available in Perl 5.10 only - and it _can_ be a problem.

Answer (score 2):

It's so called `defined-or` operator, which has been implemented in [Perl 5.10](http://perldoc.perl.org/perl5100delta.html#Defined-or-operator). Example from the doc:

> The following expression:
>
> ```
> $a // $b
> ```
>
> ... is merely equivalent to
>
> ```
> defined $a ? $a : $b
> ```
>
> And the statement:
>
> ```
> $c //= $d;
> ```
>
> ... can now be used instead of
>
> ```
> $c = $d unless defined $c;
> ```

Here's how `||` and `//` are different:

```
use 5.010;
my $rabbits = 0;
say $rabbits || 1; # 1, as 0 || 1 evaluates to 1
say $rabbits // 1; # 0, as 0 is not `undef`
```

Answer (score 1):

That is "defined-or". `$abc // "default"` is equivalent to `defined($abc) ? $abc : "default"`. Meaning if the left side of `//` has a defined value then that value is used, otherwise the right side of it.

See ["Logical defined-or" in the perlop man page](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Answer (score 0):

is `defined or`

like,

```
my $a //= 3;
```

will assign 3 to `$a`

it is different from `||`, which is simply, `or` in that:

```
my $a = ""; 
$a //= 3; 
print "|$a|\n"; 

$a = "";
$a ||=5; 
print "|$a|\n";
```

will print only `|5|`, because in the first case `$a` is defined (with a false value), while in the second it matters if `$a` evaluates to `true` or not.